# Latent variable and Factor analysis ICA

Tags: self-study, factor-analysis, covariance-matrix, svd, latent-variable

While I was going through the factor analysis for Independent component analysis, I got stuck in one statement. How does it come to **co-variance** of **S*** is **I**? Is **A*** =**AR**<sup>**T**</sup> ?

Following is what I was going through and it is given in the book [Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide details of the source? There may be imprudent context missing. My understanding was that in SVD it was $V^T$ that was orthogonal and factor analysis (in the true technical sense, not the generic sense that includes all decomposition) was required to orthogonalise U as well. Basically what it is saying is that there is no way of finding a single solution to the true independent variables based on finding uncorrelated ones using just the second moment, variance. There are an infinite number of rotations that map the latent variables back onto themselves.

Comment: It is from book Elements of Statistical Learning chapter unsupervised learning. Book is available for free on internet.

Comment: Could you put a link in the question for readers and tag as self study? I suspect that in the end its similar to the issue of the circular joint distribution of Gaussians that answers many of your ICA questions, but is more general here as we are looking at the second moment variance, which only captures orthogonality and not independence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
Cov(S^{*}) = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}[(RS)(RS)^{T}] = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}[RSS^{T}R^{T}] = R\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[SS^{T}]R^{T}
$$
where the last step holds because R is constant.
Notice that the $\sqrt{N}$ cancel out when multiplying $A$ and $S$, so we can ignore them. Now, since $U$ as well as $R$ are orthogonal, $SS^{T} = I$.